# Не работает динамическое добавление input

Tags: jquery, javascript

При добавлении вопроса все нормально.

Не работает нажатие на +, при нажатии в тот же td, должен добавляться input.

Еще подскажите, как сделать перенумерацию строк в таблице, если одна из строк была удалена.

Код на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjdypw9h/4/).

Comment: @Jashka, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Там у тебя логическая ошибка поиска элемента, к которому ты добавляешь дополнительный `<input />`, можно сделать проще:
http://jsfiddle.net/mjdypw9h/15/

По-хорошему там можно обойтись всего одним id и все расчеты вести относительно через `.closest()` / `.find()`